# sql embedded query range of cells for parameter excel 2010

Tags: sql, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to pass a range of cells through a parameter, but whenever I do, whether I make a list box or concatenate all the values, my output is empty.

Here is my SQL query:
        select distinct
        k.USN 
        ,k.is_commodity
        ,k.Import_SKU
        from ods..SKU k
        where k.usn in (?)

My parameters are in Sheet1, cells A9:A69

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub SQL()
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "select distinct k.USN ,k.is_commodity ,k.Import_SKU" & _
     "from k" & _
     "where k.usn in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A9:A69").Value), "','") & "')"
End Sub
```